# Why almost all docker library images are build from the source not from the package systems?

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile, alpine-linux

Why almost all docker library (standard) images are build from the source not from the package systems?

I've investigated https://hub.docker.com/u/library/

- https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/
- https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/
- https://hub.docker.com/_/php/
- https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

Does this have a logical explanation especially for `alpine` linux?

Comment: It's likely this is done for greater control. By building from source, the image builder has greater control over when the build is performed (e.g. GitHub checkins) and in ensuring that specific|latest versions of the code are used. Package managers inevitably trail behind.

Answer (score 1):

Official answer: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/3517

> There's not any clear answer on which to prefer simply because we
>   defer to upstream's official recommendations on a case-by-case basis.
>   For example, in the postgres image's Debian variants, we consume the
>   .deb packages built and published by the upstream project, but in the
>   Alpine variants we have to build from source (since upstream does not
>   publish Alpine packages and instead recommends building from source
>   for platforms for which they do not publish their own packages).
>
> In httpd, Apache upstream does not publish any binary packages, and we
>   thus build from source.
>
> In openjdk, we install packages built by Debian, Alpine, etc. simply
>   because OpenJDK itself is very difficult and time-consuming to build
>   from source, and because upstream officially recommends those packages
>   as a suitable source of OpenJDK.